# How to randomly select items from a numpy matrix (in a vectorized way)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy matrix of fares by products, something like

```
|--------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        |     Product 1       |     Product 2    |     Product 3    |     Product 4    |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Fare 1 |          10         |         11       |         12       |         13       |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Fare 2 |          20         |         21       |         22       |         23       |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Fare 3 |          30         |         31       |         32       |         33       |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

My goal is to randomly select a fare for each product, for a stream of days. Essentially, I expect to have something like

```
|-------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       |     Product 1       |     Product 2    |     Product 3    |     Product 4    |
|-------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Day 1 |          30         |         11       |         22       |         13       |
|-------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| Day 2 |          30         |         31       |         22       |         33       |
|-------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The only way I figured out to do that is with a classical loop:

```py
import numpy as np

generator = np.random.default_rng()
days = {1, 2}
fare_product_matrix = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [11, 21 , 31], [12, 22, 32], [13, 23, 33]])

fare_indexes = generator.integers(0, fare_product_matrix.shape[1], size=(len(days), fare_product_matrix.shape[0]))

out = np.empty(fare_indexes.shape)
for day in range(len(days)):
    for product in range(fare_product_matrix.shape[0]):
        out[day, product] = fare_product_matrix[product, fare_indexes[day, product]]
```

Is there any smart vectorized way to do that with numpy?

Comment: `out = fare_product_matrix[np.arange(fare_product_matrix.shape[0]), fare_indexes)`? (btw, note that if each row of `out` represents the fare for a corresponding day, it may not be a good idea to use a `set` for `days`, since sets do not have an order and their elements cannot be accessed by index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this:

```
rows = np.random.randint(0,fare_product_matrix.shape[0], 
                        len(days) * fare_product_matrix.shape[1])

cols = np.tile(np.arange(fare_product_matrix.shape[1]), len(days))

fare_product_matrix[rows, cols].reshape(len(days), -1)
```

Output:

```
array([[30, 21, 12, 13],
       [10, 31, 32, 23]])
```

Comment: That's perfect. Code is even clearer like that. Thanks!